# How do I create a subform that shows query results of a search on the parent form?

Tags: forms, ms-access

I'm quite new to MS Access but understand basic dvl concepts.  I have a form (SalesOrder) where I can create sales order info.  Creating a new sales order populates more than one table.

I'd like to have a two search buttons on the bottom of the form that will display the results of a query (search by customer name or order id).  The results of the query need to be displayed in a subform, and once I click on the selected row, it should populate the master form fields with read-only data (i'll have an edit button to change to writable).

Do I simply link a query to the subform?  If so, how do I do that?  and how do get the event in the main form (the search button click event) to trigger action in the subform?

thanks in advance.

jeff

Comment: Have you tried anything? There are a few different ways you could do this.

Comment: I'm halfway there.  I have a subform and the right query, but I don't know how to get the query results to post to the subform.  the problem is that i'm completely Access illiterate (I'm more familiar with doing things from scratch).  how do i get the query results to post to a form?

Comment: What does the query for the subform look like?

Comment: Me.subOrderResults.Form.RecordSource = "select so.SalesOrderID, cust.BusinessName, so.CreatedDate, con.FirstName as SalesPerson, so.CaseCount from    (((SalesOrder so inner join Customer cust on so.CustomerID = cust.CustomerID) inner join Salesperson sp on so.SalespersonID = sp.SalespersonID) inner join Contact con on sp.ContactID = con.ContactID) where so.SalesOrderID = " & Me.searchID

Comment: interestingly enough, I got it to work.  but then if i try to make any changes to the sub form (i want to add a click event so that when the user selects one of the rows, it will populate the parent form), i then get the following error: the expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist"  any idea why?

Comment: Does this apply to you? https://support.microsoft.com/kb/926700?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Are you referring to the name correctly for the Button? I know it seems silly, but it's best to check.. Referring to objects on forms/subforms can get very tedious. I love this table : http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm .. Keep this chart as long as you're developing in Access